Quaternion Algebra splits
I want to show that $(-1,b)_{\mathbb{F}}$ splits if and only if $b$ is a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{F}$. For this I want to use the fact that $(a,b)_{\mathbb{F}}$ splits if and only if $ax^2 + by^2 - z^2 = 0$ has a non-trivial solution in $\mathbb{F}^{3}$. Obviously if $y \ne 0$, then there is a non-trivial solution for $-x^2 +by^2 =  z^2$, meaning, that $b = (x/y)^2 + (z/y)^2$, which is the required representation. However I don't understand what to do if $y = 0$. Any clues?

What do you mean by $\mathbb{F}$ ? The usual notation for the field of quaternions is $\mathbb{H}$.

@JeanMarie There is no such thing as a "field" of quaternions. They form a  associative normed division algebra, when classically considered over field $\mathbb{R}$. Here i'm talking about a so-called quaternion algebra $(a,b)_\mathbb{F}$, which is four-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-algebra, with a basis ${1,i,j,ij}$ such that the classic quaternion relations hold: $ij = -ji$, $i^2 = a$ and $j^2 =b$.

For me (and for some others too, I think) the quaternions constitute a skew (non commutative) field. See for example this recent publication.

@JeanMarie Division ring and skew field are the same thing, and though skew field has a word field in it is not an example of a field (it is actually the other way around any field is a skew field. This is because skew fields are not necessarily commutative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring,

@JeanMarie Moreover, once again $\mathbb{F}$ here is indeed a field, and $(a,b)_{\mathbb{F}}$ are the "generalized version" of quaternions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra

@MatthewWillow It is not very common anymore, but former usage did permit (at least, it could be interpreted that way), especially in some other languages,  using the word "field" for division rings.  So in this case it is quite understandable, and not necessary to speak dogmatically of definitions.

@rschwieb Thanks. Interesting reference. I wouldn't have asked this question had the asker said at once that $\mathbb{F}$ is a (commutative :)) field, fully "external" to quaternions.

@rschwieb I did not want to offend anyone, it just occurred to me, that the comment was missing the point of my question and concentrating on a rather detached topic of $\mathbb{H}$ notion.

Makes sense. I could not quite gauge what was going on.

I will assume that $\mathrm{char}(\Bbb F) \neq 2$. Quadratic forms are a bit weird in characteristic two, as are quaternion algebras.
If $-x^2+by^2-z^2=0$ has a nontrivial solution with $y=0$, then every element of $\Bbb F$ is a sum of two squares. Here are two ways to see this:

(Without explicit computation, relying on the theory of quadratic forms): A non-trivial solution to $-x^2+by^2-z^2=0$ means that we get that the quadratic form $x^2+z^2$ represents zero non-trivially. By a general theorem about quadratic forms, this implies that $x^2+z^2$ is universal, i.e. it represents every element of $\Bbb F$.

(Without theory, by explicit (and quite random) computation): A nontrivial solution $x^2+z^2=0$ implies by an easy argument that there is some $i \in \Bbb F$ such that $i^2=-1$. Now take any element $c \in \Bbb F$. Then $(c+\frac{i}{2})^2=c^2+ic-\frac{1}{4}$ and $(ic+\frac{1}{2})^2=-c^2+ic+\frac{1}{4}$. Thus $$(c+\frac{i}{2})^2+(ic+\frac{1}{2})^2=2ic$$ Now $2i=(1+i)^2$, so we get that


$$\left(\frac{c+\frac{i}{2}}{i+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ic+\frac{1}{2}}{i+1}\right)^2=c$$

good.  I was going to point out that, except characteristic two, everything is a difference of two squares in a field. $\left( \frac{x}{4} + 1 \right)^2  - \left( \frac{x}{4} - 1 \right)^2  .$   Then if $-1$ is a square...

@WillJagy yes, that's easier.

@LukasHeger Makes sense, thanks!
